# Form associations: Having trouble with controller saving information to 2 models simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, html-table, associations

For my project I am trying to build a dashboard whereby an Agent can view submissions posted by a user and add a Status & Notes to each submission in order to log their own personal activity i.e they would not be changing the actual record, just leaving private notes against it. In order to do this I have created a join table with both Agent id and Submission id as well as Status and Notes columns.

I have managed to create an index view that shows submissions data with 2 form fields at the end of each line from my join table which are called Status and Notes... the problem is when I update these fields they do not get saved to my jointable.

Form on index view

```
  <%= form_with(model: submission, local: true) do |form| %>
      <% form.fields_for :agent_activities do |act| %>

      <td> <div class="field">

        <%= act.text_field :Status %>

      </div>
    </td>

    <td> <div class="field">

      <%= act.text_field :Notes %>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
</td>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Model associations in rb files

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, :optional => true

  belongs_to :location, :optional => true

  has_many :agent_activities

end


class AgentActivity < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :submission, :optional => true #has submission_id 
  foreign key in table

  belongs_to :agent, :optional => true #has agent_id foreign key in 
  table


end
```

Controller:

```
 class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_submission, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
@submissions = Submission.where(:user_id => current_user.id)

end


def show
end


def new
@submission = Submission.new
end


def edit
end

# POST /submissions
# POST /submissions.json
def create
@submission = Submission.new(submission_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))

respond_to do |format|
  if @submission.save
    # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome email after save
    NewSubmissionMailer.submission_email(@submission).deliver_now
    NewSubmissionMailer.matching_agents_email(@submission).deliver_now

    format.html { redirect_to @submission, notice: 'Submission was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @submission }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @submission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
 end

 # PATCH/PUT /submissions/1
 # PATCH/PUT /submissions/1.json
  def update
  respond_to do |format|
  if @submission.update(submission_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @submission, notice: 'Submission was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @submission }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @submission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end

 end

# DELETE /submissions/1
# DELETE /submissions/1.json
def destroy
@submission.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to submissions_url, notice: 'Submission was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

 private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_submission
  @submission = Submission.find(params[:id])
  end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def submission_params
  params.require(:submission).permit(:First_Name, :Last_Name, :Phone, :Email, :Desired_Location, :number_of_beds, :number_of_occupants, :Rent_price_per_month_gbp, :Max_move_in_date, :Tenant_Occupation, :Contact_me_on, :Furnished, :Current_Address, :Property_Requirements)
end
end
```

Not sure what im missing here :/

**UPDATE BASED OFF @TOM ANSWER**

New controller params:

```
  def submission_params
  params.require(:submission).permit(:First_Name, :Last_Name, :Phone, :Email, :Desired_Location, :number_of_beds, :number_of_occupants, :Rent_price_per_month_gbp, :Max_move_in_date, :Tenant_Occupation, :Contact_me_on, :Furnished, :Current_Address, :Property_Requirements, agent_activities_attributes: [:id, :Status, :Notes, :_destroy])
end
```

end

New Submission Model rb:

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user, :optional => true

 belongs_to :location, :optional => true

 has_many :agent_activities

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :agent_activities

end
```

Index.html.erb

```
  <%= form_with(model: submission, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% form.fields_for :agent_activities, @submission.agent_activities.build do |act| %>
      <td> <div class="field">

        <%= act.text_field :Status %>

      </div>
    </td>

    <td> <div class="field">

      <%= act.text_field :Notes %>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
</td>

    <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your controller? Specifically your strong parameters? Did you add the new `status` and `notes` as keys in your permitted parameters?

Comment: Updated now, no I have not included status and notes included params because I figured that I would not be updating any of the columns in the submissions model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On your `Submission` model add: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :agent_activities` ([accepts_nested_attributes_for documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)) This will let Rails know that your form is going to be supplying fields for an associated model.
2. Once that is added Rails will be supplying a key in params `agent_activities_attributes` in your strong params we can add: `.permit(..., agent_activities_attributes: [:id, :Status, :Notes, :_destroy]`.  The `:_destroy` key is only needed if you plan on having `allow_destroy: true` on the nested attribute call.

One side note: Capitalized names (`Status`, `Notes`, etc) are normally reserved for constants in Ruby.  You may want to look into changing your attribute column names to lowercase.

Comment: Thanks @Tom very helpful although my form fields on my index view seem to now have disappeared?

Comment: Try `<% form.fields_for :agent_activities, @submission.agent_activities.build do |act| %>` This will supply a record object in the event there are no pre existing agent_activities. OR try `form_with(model: @submission..` using the instance variable instead of a symbol reference.

Comment: So the second option seems to work, however, my button has changed from updated to save and it is now asking me to save to a completely different model (called estate agents) which isn't working because I have not added to the required params for it.

Comment: estate agents?? could that be a typo somewhere?

Comment: It seems to be coming from me using the instance variable as opposed to the symbol reference in the form